# Passing data in haskell

Tags: haskell, methods

My question is about passing data in Haskell. This is my code:

```
c1 x y = x^y
c3 x y = let
    z1 = c1(x y)
    in (z1)
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

How would I pass data from one method to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Thilo's answer: in Haskell, `f x y` is *not* parsed as something like `f (x y)`, instead it's actually parsed as `(f x) y`. That seems at first sight to make little sense, but actually it's perfectly reasonable – the technique is called [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Its advantage will become obvious when you're dealing with *higher-order functions*.

Normally, you don't need to worry about this – just *never put parenthesis around function-argument listings*. Only put parentheses around *single* arguments, when they're expressions that need to be encapsulated.

- Don't:

  ```
  sin (x)
  ```

  (Though that's in principle perfectly legal.) Do:

  ```
  sin x
  ```
- Don't:

  ```
  max (7 5)
  ```

  which would be parsed as application of the function `7` to the argument `5`... clearly nonsense. Do:

  ```
  max 7 5
  ```
- Don't:

  ```
  sin pi*x
  ```

  which would be parsed as `(sin pi) * x`, aka `0`. Do:

  ```
  sin (pi*x)
  ```

  or, preferrably unless it requires putting extra parens around the entire thing,

  ```
  sin $ pi*x
  ```

Comment: That makes more sense now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in other languages, you do not call a Haskell function with a parameter list in parentheses.

It should be just `c1 x y` -- or `(c1 x y)` if you need to embed it in a bigger expression.

`c1 (x y)` would have called `c1` on the result of `x` (a function itself!) being called with parameter `y`.